# MediaWiKi User Registration

Tags: symfony1, mediawiki

I have a website developed in symfony (1.2.9). I want to add a wiki to the website, and have opted for mediawiki.

I want to integrate mediawiki with my website in a way such that:

1. media wiki does not create new users
2. users logged into my website are automatically logged into mediawiki (and vice versa)
3. ideally, I want to use the same login process (i.e. screen) for both my website and mediawiki

I have spent a few hours trawling the web on how to do this, and have found nothing. Hopefully someone on here may have done this before, or atleast, can shed some light on how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If your website and mediawiki runs in same domain, you could consider using [OpenID](http://openid.net/).

MediaWiki have [extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OpenID) for it and seems for [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfOpenIDPlugin) too.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same thing with Django. I suspect it will involve hacking the underlying tables.

User creation is NOT supported through the API:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit_-_Register_new_user

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the [AuthPlugin](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/AuthPlugin) by doing:

```
class myauth extends AuthPlugin {
     ...
}
```

Or as above: use OpenID logins for both.